# How to pass implicit parameter to Closure in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, grails-orm

I have many queries that have the same logic and I decided to extract it into closure.

Here is an example:

```
Closure whereByProjectIdAndUser = { Criteria cr, Long projectId, User user ->
    Long userId = user.id
    Boolean isReviewer = user.isReviewer()

    cr.isNull 'project.deletedAt'
    cr.eq 'project.id', projectId

    (cr | {
        cr.eq 'owner.id', userId

        if (isReviewer) {
            cr & {
                cr.eq 'reviewer.id', userId
                cr.ne 'project.certificationStatus', ProjectCertificationStatus.None
            }
        }
    })
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
RrmUtilization[] getAllByProjectIdAndUser(Long projectId, User user) {

    BuildableCriteria cr = RrmUtilization.createCriteria()
    RrmUtilization[] result = cr.list {
        createAlias('project', 'project', JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
        createAlias('project.owner', 'owner', JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
        createAlias('project.reviewer', 'reviewer', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

        isNull 'deletedAt'

        whereByProjectIdAndUser(cr, projectId, user)

    } as RrmUtilization[]

    result
}
```

This works just fine, however, I was trying to understand how can I avoid explicitly passing BuildableCriteria into the closure? Is there a way to have it implicitly passed through and get a nicer code?

Maybe there are some better approaches in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `this` to access parameters in the enclosing class of the closure.

Groovy documentation: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#closure-owner